# How can I make it so that my UIView is always flush with the right side of my screen without autolayout?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get my UIView to always stay on the right hand side of the screen:

```
let yPosition: CGFloat = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isPortrait ? 54.0 : 38.0
self.customView = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, yPosition, 255, 306.8))
self.view.addSubview(self.customView!)
```

Comment: If you use Autolayout this is very easy (plenty of tutorials exist, just google for them)

Comment: I'm not using autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let yPosition: CGFloat = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isPortrait ? 54.0 : 38.0
self.customView = CustomView()
self.customView!.frame.size = CGSize(width: 255, height: 306.8)
self.customView!.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width - self.customView!.frame.size.width, yPosition)
self.view.addSubview(self.customView!)
```

Comment: self.customView!.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width - self.customView!.frame.size.width, yPosition)